# How to properly access Realm instance in a Service?

Tags: android, socket.io, android-service, realm

I'm having trouble accessing a Realm instance inside a `Service` class which I'm using to handle a `Socket.IO` connection. I'm getting a `Realm` instance on the `onStartCommand` call like this.

```
public class SocketService extends Service{
    Realm realmInstance;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        realmInstance = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }
}
```

The problem is when I bind to a socket event, upon receiving that event I need to store some data into `Realm` but it throws an exception indicating the `Realm` object can't be accessed in a thread other than the one it was created on.

```
socket.on("register", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                List<MyRealmObject> list = realmInstance.where(MyRealmObject.class).findAll();
            }
        });
```

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread.
>   Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created

I event tried creating a separate instance for my event calls which I instantiated inside `CONNECT` call of socket.io to no avail.

Comment: See https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#threading . the `call()` is running on a different thread from where the `realmInstance` created on. You might need to call `getDefaultInstance()` in the call method to get a dedicate instance for that thread. Don't forget to close the instance after using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {` runs on the UI thread.

`public void call(Object... args) {` runs on a background thread.

They are not the same thread. Each thread requires its own Realm instance (if you access the Realm on the thread). On background threads that cannot auto-update, you must close the Realm instance when it is no longer needed.

```
socket.on("register", new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
                List<MyRealmObject> list = realm.where(MyRealmObject.class).findAll();
            } // try-with-resources auto-close
        }
    });
```